# Is it possible to set the matrix weights of embeddings before or after training word2vec?

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec

I need to change the matrix embedding in word2vec after to train this. Here is the example:

```
w2v=Word2Vec(sentences,size=100,window=1,min_count=1,negative=15,iter=3)
w2v.save("word2vec.model")

#Getting embedding matrix
embedding_matrix=w2v.wv.vectors

for p in ("mujer", "hombre"):
    result=w2v.wv.similar_by_word(p)
    print("Similar words from '",p,"': ",result[:3])

#Trying to set wights matrix
w2v.wv.vectors=np.random.rand(w2v.wv.vectors.shape[0],w2v.wv.vectors.shape[1])

print()

for p in ("mujer", "hombre"):
    result=w2v.wv.similar_by_word(p)
    print("Similar words from '",p,"': ",result[:3])
```

And here is the output:

```
Similar words from ' mujer ':  [('honra', 0.9999152421951294), ('muerte', 0.9998959302902222), ('contento', 0.999891459941864)]
Similar words from ' hombre ':  [('valor', 0.9999064207077026), ('nombre', 0.9998984336853027), ('llegar', 0.9998887181282043)]

Similar words from ' mujer ':  [('honra', 0.9999152421951294), ('muerte', 0.9998959302902222), ('contento', 0.999891459941864)]
Similar words from ' hombre ':  [('valor', 0.9999064207077026), ('nombre', 0.9998984336853027), ('llegar', 0.9998887181282043)]
```

As you can see, I get the same predictions despite having changed the embedding matrix by random numbers.

I don't get any method in the documentation to make this change.

Will it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution. Just use the [init_sims](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.init_sims)() function after setting the array.

```
w2v=Word2Vec(sentences,size=100,window=1,min_count=1,negative=15,iter=3)
w2v.save("word2vec.model")

#Getting embedding matrix
embedding_matrix=w2v.wv.vectors

for p in ("mujer", "hombre"):
    result=w2v.wv.similar_by_word(p)
    print("Similar words from '",p,"': ",result[:3])

#Setting new values on wights matrix
w2v.wv.vectors=np.random.rand(w2v.wv.vectors.shape[0],w2v.wv.vectors.shape[1])

#This line create a l2 normalization over the embedding matrix 
word_vectors.vectors_norm=word_vectors.init_sims(replace=False)

print()

for p in ("mujer", "hombre"):
    result=w2v.wv.similar_by_word(p)
    print("Similar words from '",p,"': ",result[:3])
```

Comment: You may not want to use the `replace=True` option, as that will have extra side-effects that lose some information: it will merge both the `vectors` and `vectors_norm` properties into a single array, with **only** the unit-normalized versions of all vectors. If the original raw magnitudes of the vectors were important, that will be lost. (On the other hand, if you will **only** be doing comparisons based on `most_similar()` and other functions using only unit-normalized vectors, forcing that `replace=True` will save some memory.)

Comment: It is true. To continue training you must use replace=False

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can generally tamper with an object's internal properties, because there's no "protection" making them invisible or unmodifiable from outside code.

Try assigning to `w2v.wv.vectors` (no underscore `_vectors` as in your original question).

Or, directly to an individual vector: `w2v.wv['mujer'] = np.random.rand(100)`.

These should change the model; however **if** you've already performed `most_similar()` (and related functions), the model **also** caches some interim, unit-length-normalized versions of the `vectors` – and your direct tampering **won't** update that. You can clear this cache with:

```
del w2v.wv.vectors_norm
```